# Add the name to the output of the sed command

Tags: awk, sed

I want to perform the command sed on a file and getting the result into multiple file

Ex input file

```
test_1
step 1
...
result
step 2
...
result
step 3
...
result
test end
....
test_2
step 1
...
result
step 2
...
result
test end
```

I'm using the following command to get the lines between "test X" and "test end"

```
sed -n "/test/,/test end/p" input.txt > output
```

I would like to output the result of this command into new files,
which the name will be for this example test_1.txt, test_2.txt.
and file contents will be

test_1.txt

```
    test_1
    step 1
    ...
    result
    step 2
    ...
    result
    step 3
    ...
    result
    test end
```

test_2.txt

```
test_2
step 1
...
result
step 2
...
result
test end
```

Comment: Are there any parts of the file that you don't want to print, or do you just want to split it up?

Comment: I want to keep just the parts between the tags "test_X" & "test end"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this using awk:

```
awk '/test/{f=1;++file}/test end/{f=0}f{print > "test_" file}' input
```

When /test/ is matched, set `f` to true and increment `file`. When /test end/ is matched, set `f` to false. When `f` is true, print the line to the file whose name contains the value of the variable `file`.

Comment: worked like a charm, thank you.
what if the begin of the match was "test_X" and X is not a number 
and the output file name should be test_X.txt?